# How to replace a spaced comma in a string?

Tags: python, string

I have the following string which I want to parse into words. Here is string sentence

```
text = "If it is hot , don’t touch"
```

What I've tried so far:

```
import string

text = "If it is hot , don’t touch"

words = [word.replace(',', '') for word in text.split()]
print(words)
```

However I've got following result:

```
['If', 'it', 'is', 'hot', '', 'don’t', 'touch']
```

What I want as a result:

```
['If', 'it', 'is', 'hot', 'don’t', 'touch']
```

Comment: Do your replace on `text`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to replace space-comma-space with one space, and then do a regular split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
text = "If it is hot , don’t touch"
newtext = text.replace(",", "")
words = newtext.split()
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a filter function, instead of the replace finction of ',' with ' '
you can use a function that returns only the words which is not equal to ','
like this:

```
words = [word for word in text.split() if word!=',']
```